# Incorrect pixel coordinates

Tags: wpf

I am using the following code to get pixel coordinates of the mouse position.

```
private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     startPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
}
```

However, if the user uses the scroll bar to move down a bit then this code does not work. I get the wrong coordinates and the object does not get drawn under the mouse position. Any ideas what going on here?

Comment: When you say "wrong coordinates", do they simply fail to scroll with it?  Have you tried getting the data vs the scrollviewer instead of the canvas?

Comment: Hi, I am not quiet sure what you mean by "data vs scrollviewer". I want to use the mouse position to draw an object on the screen but it seems that if we scroll the window (using ScrollViewer) it doesn't work anymore. The object gets drawn in the wrong location

Comment: I meant, instead of using `this`, try using the scrollViewer.  That actually won't work tho, and will give you the type of error you are seeing.  I just wrote a sample app that works fine using `this` = the canvas, and it worked fine.  Not sure what is going on with your code.  How are you drawing the object?  Can you add more code to your question (e.g. some stripped down xaml and some of your drawing code) so we can figure this out?

Comment: Actually I think I might have figured it out.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing should (more or less) work.  You might have some problem with exactly which `MouseMove` event you are listening to, though.

Here is a sample app that demonstrates the desired behavior.

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="12">
        <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                MouseMove="ScrollViewer_MouseMove">
            <Canvas Name="canvas" Width="800" Height="600" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition(canvas);
            var rectangle = new Rectangle
            {
                RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(
                    mousePosition.X,
                    mousePosition.Y),
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            };
            canvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

The key here is I bound the `MouseMove` event to the `ScrollViewer`, and checked the position of the `Canvas`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Your earlier answer about using "canvas" instead of "this" worked perfectly! It may seem trivial but I am fairly new to this :)